# How to fix right-aligned text setting in VS2008's Properties Window?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

While working in the Properties Window today in Visual Studio 2008, I somehow managed to hit a keyboard shortcut that changed the text alignment from left-aligned to right-aligned. Note that I am not asking how to set the right-to-left property of a control. I am talking about the Properties Window itself in Visual Studio 2008. I tried looking for this setting in Visual Studio but I could not find it.

[image: Properties Window right-to-left]

How can I fix this so that the Properties Window shows the Property values left-aligned again?

**Edit**

If it helps any, the entering of text into the Property Window now seems to follow a right-to-left nature. For example, entering an underscore into a value places the underscore to the left of the text, even though the cursor is on the right-side of the text. This causes `"foo" + "_" to become "_foo" and not "foo_"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have a value for a property selected, right click and deselect the "Right to left Reading order" option in the context menu provided.

Comment: That definitely worked. I must have somehow bumped the keyboard button that brings up the right-click context menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I just faced the same problem with you.

The properties value is set to right-align when I press RightCtrl + RightShift + S.
It will change back to left-align when I press LeftCtrl + LeftShift + S.
Need to select on property value & not the property name when doing this.

Ctrl + Shift + S should be Save All but I'm not sure why it has this feature / bug.

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue using these shortcuts but I was not able to. Perhaps this is a keyboard shortcut specific to the [general environment settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhkx167(v=VS.90).aspx)? Mine started out as Visual Basic settings and has some custom ones I set.