# Visual Studio 2010 Properties Panel text align to the right

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, properties, appearance

I've been fiddling with a property of a control in Windows Forms, and suddenly, I don't know how, I clicked something in the Properties Panel, and all the text in the panel got aligned to the right. I have a picture here to show you. I am stuck with this panel, and it is really annoying. Could you please help me? Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: [Have you tried this approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335270/how-to-fix-right-aligned-text-setting-in-vs2008s-properties-window).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have Right-to-Left reading order enabled. To fix it, find a text box in the properties window that you can enter free text (like where you would enter the ID/Name for a control). Right click in the text box, and uncheck "Right to left Reading order":

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I do not have this menu item in my Visual Studio. But, when I restarted the computer and launched visual studio, the text in the Properties Panel have restored to its original. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Remember the good old key stroke: "CTRL + Z" It will take you right back!

Comment: Based off vcsjones' answer, Ctrl-Z does not undo the text alignment.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnNol.png)

Right Click on the text Property textbox there is a option to change it !

Comment: Isn't this the same answer as the accepted post from three years ago?